# TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined at admin.firestore.collection.doc.collection.doc.get.then.queryResult

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I'm losing my mind over here :/
I'm trying the Functions of Firebase to send notification between users.

The function seem alright and get the path successfully (checked it on the log) but still when attempting to access the document the return is "no document" even though it exists.
I went through quite a few similar questions but didn't find a solution, please help :)

This is the function:

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("users/{user_id}/notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context) =>{ 

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
    console.log("User ID: " + user_id + " | Notification ID: " + notification_id);

    return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user_id).collection("notifications").doc("notification_id").get().then(queryResult =>{
            if (!queryResult.exists) {
                    console.log('No documents');
                    return null;

            }else{
                const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;

                const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(from_user_id).get();
                const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user_id).get();

                return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result =>{

                    const from_name = reuslt[0].data().name;
                    const to_name = reuslt[1].data().name;

                    console.log("FROM: " + from_name + " TO: " + to_name);
                    return null;
                });
            }
    }).catch(err =>{ console.error('Error getting document', err); }); });
```

and this is from firebase:

> 1:00:23.767 AM sendNotification Function execution took 189 ms, finished with status: 'error'
>
> 1:00:23.762 AMsendNotification TypeError: Cannot read property 'from'
>   of undefined at
>   admin.firestore.collection.doc.collection.doc.get.then.queryResult
>   (/user_code/index.js:15:44) at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
>
> 1:00:23.585 AM sendNotification
>   User ID: mpIfC6Ca41eBdwNzwwX3GJaHIfb2 | Notification ID: v89cRRcV2np8IsAwbRu0
>
> 1:00:23.578 AM sendNotification Function execution started

Answer (score 3):

Wrote ("notification_id") in the path instead of (notification_id) as in the const I created.

Only 2 hours to figure that out :|